# C++ Remove last comma when printing AVL tree elements

Tags: c++, recursion, avl-tree

I know similar questions have been asked but I can't seem to find an answer for printing via a recursively called function. I am trying to print preorder, postorder, and inorder traversals of an AVL tree and have implemented the functions recursively.

i.e.

```
void inOrder(Node* root)
{
    if(root != nullptr) {
        inOrder(root->left);
        cout << root->data << ", ";
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}
```

The data should print comma-separated except for the last value, but I am not sure how to do so. I've done research but can't find anything that seems to apply when traversing an AVL tree recursively. Is this possible or should I implement the functions without recursion?

Comment: You don't want to write a comma after the last node. Now you just have to figure out what the last node is and how to detect it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's usually easier to detect the first node rather than the last. Thus you would usually skip the delimiter before the first element rather than after the last one.

Comment: What happens if you want to do something else other than print a node in your traversals?  If you thought about it this way, then maybe you would think of implementing the traversal code a little differently, other than hardcoding a specific action (such as printing) in the traversal.

Comment: @deW1 There may be multiple tree nodes with `nullptr` right branch. Such nodes might not be final in the iteration.

Comment: @AndreySemashev true i forgot it's a tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an internal implementation function that maintains a flag that indicates whether the data item to be output is the first one. Then prepend the output with a comma for all items but the first.

```
void inOrderImpl(Node* root, bool& first)
{
    if(root != nullptr) {
        inOrderImpl(root->left, first);
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            cout << ", ";
        cout << root->data;
        inOrderImpl(root->right, first);
    }
}

void inOrder(Node* root)
{
    bool first = true;
    inOrderImpl(root, first);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I usually use for this sort of thing is to use a separator pointer that I change in the loop. The first iteration it's `""`, so prints nothing, and every subsequent iteration prints the separator. For your recursive case it would be passed as a parameter, and look like this:

```
void inOrder(Node* root, char ** sep)
{
    if(root != nullptr) {
        inOrder(root->left, sep);
        cout << **sep << root->data;
        *sep = ", ";
        inOrder(root->right, sep);
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```
char * sep = "";
inOrder(root, &sep);
```

It looks a lot nicer for loops. The main advantage is there is no if/else branch in every loop, just a fast pointer assignment to update the separator.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment suggested, an ambitious (and better) way to write the code to do any of the BST traversals would be to use a more generic approach:

```
template <typename Fn>
void inOrder(Node* root, Fn& func)
{
    if(root != nullptr) 
    {
        inOrder(root->left, func);
        func(root);
        inOrder(root->right, func);
    }
}
```

So given the above, you can basically do anything, since `func` will be called using the current value of `root`.

So how does this help us?  Consider now the following:

```
struct TreePrinter
{ 
   bool initial = true; 
   void operator()(Node *root)
   {
     if ( initial )
        initial = false;
     else
        std::cout << ",";
    std::cout << root->data;
   }
};
```

The above is a class that has overriden `operator()`.  This allows us to pass this to the traversal function, and the traversal function simply calls it.

Note that the `initial` is a state that gets set in the `TreePrinter` object.

Then this is how it's implemented:

```
TreePrinter tp;
Node root;
//...
inOrder(&root, tp);
```

Here is a [live example using a dummy BST](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4a4be783ea610f3).

So not only can you just print a comma, any callable object (function pointer, function object, lambda, etc.) can be provided that can basically use the passed in `root` to do whatever needs to be done.